# making form updates more concise in vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, node-modules

I have the code below. It works but it is extremely complicated and lengthy for no reason. I was wondering if there was a more effective way to do what I am trying to do.

```
          <h6><label for="number">Change Number</label></h6>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="number"
            v-model="weather.number"
            name="number"
          />
          <h6><label for="password">Change Password</label></h6>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="password"
            v-model="weather.password"
            name="password"
          />   
          <h6><label for="time">Change Time</label></h6>
            <select
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="time"
              required
              v-model="weather.time"
              name="time"
            >
              <option value="1">1 AM</option>
              <option value="2">2 AM</option>
              <option value="3">3 AM</option>
            </select>   
            <button @click="saveInput" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Vue Javascript below the html:

```
saveInput() {
  if ((this.weather.password != '') && (this.weather.number != '') && (this.weather.time != '') ) {
    data = {
      email: this.$route.params.data[0].email,
      password: this.weather.password,
      number: this.weather.number,
      time: this.weather.time,
      state: this.weather.state
    }
  }
  else if ((this.weather.number != '') && (this.weather.time != '')) {
    data = {
      email: this.$route.params.data[0].email,
      password: this.$route.params.data[0].password,
      number: this.weather.number,
      time: this.weather.time,
      state: this.weather.state
    }
  }
  else if ((this.weather.password != '') && (this.weather.time != '')) {
    data = {
      email: this.$route.params.data[0].email,
      password: this.weather.password,
      number: this.$route.params.data[0].number,
      time: this.weather.time,
      state: this.weather.state
    }
  }
  else if ((this.weather.number != '') && (this.weather.password != '')) {
    data = {
      email: this.$route.params.data[0].email,
      password: this.weather.password,
      number: this.weather.number,
      time: this.$route.params.data[0].time,
      state: this.weather.state
    }
  }
  else {
    data = {
      email: this.$route.params.data[0].email,
      password: this.$route.params.data[0].number,
      number: this.$route.params.data[0].number,
      time: this.$route.params.data[0].time,
      state: this.weather.state
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I am basically checking to see if the user updates his or her data by submitting the form If a category is not updated, I just use the data from the backend route. How can I make this more concise so that data updates whenever a user submits a change on teh form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline operator ||. It means that if before || value is Undefined then the value after || will by default.

```
data = {
  email: this.$route.params.data[0].email,
  password: this.weather.password || this.$route.params.data[0].password,
  number: this.weather.number || this.$route.params.data[0].number,
  time: this.weather.time || this.$route.params.data[0].time,
  state: this.weather.state
}
```

And then you don't have to interpret a bunch of 'if / else if'

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

1. On the templating part I would suggest you to wrap the input elements into components `<my-input>`, it may help you reduce the code.
2. On the scripting part, the best practice to validate forms is to use a package such as [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) or [VeeValidate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4). e.g: Validating an input using VeeValidate v3:

```
<validation-provider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
  <input v-model="value" name="myinput" type="text" />
  <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</validation-provider>
```

Good luck mate.